# Class app\models\user not found yii2

Tags: php, server, yii2

I did user authentication on yii2 and in the local it works just find but after when I pulled it to server I'm getting this error Class 'app\models\user' not found and this is the marked area I'm getting

```
 $identity = $class::findIdentity($id);
```

, does anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Your local environment is windows and the server environment is unix/linux like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are storing class name in variable, use full namespace with leading slash:

```
$class = '\app\models\User';
$identity = $class::findIdentity($id);
```

Also make sure the class with this name and namespace really exists.

And the class name should start with capital letter - `User`, not `user`. It helps to avoid possible problems with letter case on different OS.

Comment: @TomWininger Glad to help. Please accept the asnwer in this case.